# Insufficient system memory in resource pool 'default' to run this query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a server with Windows Server 2012 R2 and SQL SERVER 2014 with in-memory tables, and when I do multiple deletes and inserts at those tables, I have the following problem: "There is insufficient system memory in resource pool 'default' to run this query.". But my server have 32GB of RAM and the CPU processing doesn't even reach 70%. This server only contains one database. The resource governor is enabled with 70% of max memory. I also have another server with Windows Server 2008 R2 and SQL SERVER 2014 with same process of inserts and deletes and I don't have any problem.

Any idea?

Comment: It isnt your server, its where your ssms studio is running(at least it was for me). I ran into the same thing, either return less data/close some tabs on ssms/ or restart ssms

Comment: Have restarted the server and its services and nothing...

Comment: not the server and its service. SSMS, your mangement studio. Close some tabs on your management studio or restart Management Studio

Comment: The problem is occurring when exists many inserts, is a job that run overnight.

Comment: I think that this link can help anyone who is here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995718/there-is-insufficient-system-memory-in-resource-pool-default-to-run-this-query?rq=4