# Importing a sql script using sqlcmd throws "insufficient system memory error"

Tags: sqlcmd

I am trying to import a 50mb sql file using sqlcmd but it throws the following error:

```
There is insufficient system memory in resource pool 'default' to run this query error.
```

[sqlcmd import error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmdSD.png)

I am running SQL server 2019 Developer in an EC2 instance having 4GB memory. SQL server is set to use default memory (2147483647 MB). I also tried with sql service in single user mode by running "*NET START MSSQLSERVER /f /mSQLCMD*" but still no luck. Can anyone suggest what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is fixed by adding a **GO** statement after every thousand rows as suggested by @Remus Rusanu here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1995728.